# Build a reactive publication with additional fields in each document

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-publications

I want to make a publication with several additional fields, but I don't want to either use `Collection.aggregate` and lose my publication updates when the collection change (so I can't just use `self.added` in it either).

I plan to use `Cursor.observeChanges` in order to achieve that. I have two major constraints:

1. I don't want to publish all the documents fields
2. I want to use some of the unpublished fields to create new ones. For example, I have a field `item` where I store an array of `item` _id. I don't want to publish it, but I want to publish a `item_count` field with the length of my field array

Here comes the approach:

1. I plan to chain find queries. I never did that so I wonder if it possible. The general (simplified) query structure would be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Billybobbonnet/1cgrqouj/ (I cant get the code properly displayed here)
2. Based on [the count example in Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish), I store my query in a variable `handle` in order to stop the changes notification if a client unsubscribes:

```
self.onStop(function () {
  handle.stop();
});
```

3. I add a flag `initializing = true;` before my query and I set it to `true` just before calling `self.ready();`. I use this flag to change my `itemCount` variable only if it is the publication is initialized. So basically, I change my `switch` like that:

```
switch (field) {
  case "item"
    if (!initializing)
      itemCount = raw_document.item.length;
      break;
  default:
}
```

I wanted to check that this approach is good and possible before committing into big changes in my code. Can someone confirm me if this is the right way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's relatively easy to keep fields private even if they are part of the database query. The last argument to `self.added` is the object being passed to the client, so you can strip/modify/delete fields you are sending to the client.

Here's a modified version of your fiddle. This should do what you are asking for. (To be honest I'm not sure why you had anything chained after the `observeChanges` function in your fiddle, so maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but looking at the rest of your question this should be it. Sorry if I got it wrong.)

```
var self = this;

// Modify the document we are sending to the client.
function filter(doc) {
  var length = doc.item.length;

  // White list the fields you want to publish.
  var docToPublish = _.pick(doc, [
      'someOtherField'
  ]);

  // Add your custom fields.
  docToPublish.itemLength = length;

  return docToPublish;                        
}

var handle = myCollection.find({}, {fields: {item:1, someOtherField:1}})
            // Use observe since it gives us the the old and new document when something is changing. 
            // If this becomes a performance issue then consider using observeChanges, 
            // but its usually a lot simpler to use observe in cases like this.
            .observe({
                added: function(doc) {
                    self.added("myCollection", doc._id, filter(doc));
                },
                changed: function(newDocument, oldDocument)
                    // When the item count is changing, send update to client.
                    if (newDocument.item.length !== oldDocument.item.length)
                        self.changed("myCollection", newDocument._id, filter(newDocument));
                },
                removed: function(doc) {
                    self.removed("myCollection", doc._id);                    
                });

self.ready();

self.onStop(function () {
  handle.stop();
});
```

Comment: I take my hat off, sir. This is a nice answer and your approach works like a charm. I have 10 custom fields (not only counts) on 16 white-listed total. Do you think it is wise (performance-wise) to trigger the `self.changed` every time, even if it won't effectively change the output for client? Or should I check my 10 properties before `self.changed`?

Comment: By the way, concerning the `observeChanges`, I just expected it to return the same cursor extended with functions to observe it. I tried several setups, but as a beginner, I feel it was out of my league to come up with a solution such as yours.

Comment: Glad it works!

"Do you think it is wise (performance-wise) to trigger the self.changed every time, even if it won't effectively change the output for client?"

I think a sound approach is to keep it simple when you can. If it becomes a performance issue later you deal with it at that point. We use this a lot at our production meteor site and we haven't run into any major issues yet. 

Btw, this will only update the document if `item.length` changes. If you want updates to your other 16 fields you should remove the `item.length` `if` in the `changed` callback so you always call `self.changed`.

Comment: I already made heavy changes to your code and it works great. Both from a performance (as far as I can say) and simplicity. it works great. I love the white-list approach, that's a great use of underscore that I hadn't discovered yet :-)

Comment: I have an additional question: does using `added` or simply `Cursor.observe` make a `return` before the query unnecessary?

Comment: If you return a cursor from a publication Meteor will notice that and behind the scenes it will use added/changed/removed for you (and also take care of stopping the handle when the subscription stops). If you use those callbacks yourself your publication should not return a cursor.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your first problem, you need to tell MongoDB what fields it should return in the cursor. Leave out the fields you don't want:

```
MyCollection.find({}, {fields: {'a_field':1}});
```

Solving your second problem is also pretty easy, I would suggest using the [collection helpers packages](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-collection-helpers). You could accomplish this easily, like so:

```
// Add calculated fields to MyCollection.
MyCollection.helpers({
  item_count: function() {
    return this.items.length;
  }
});
```

This will be run before an object is added to a cursor, and will create properties on the returned objects that are calculated dynamically, not stored in MongoDB.