# Meteor: group documents and publish an object

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would like to know how to group documents according to a condition, and publish to the client.

Suppose I have the following documents:

```
[
  { name: 'John', createdAt: some_date_value_1 },
  { name: 'Jane', createdAt: some_date_value_2 },
  { name: 'Bob', createdAt: some_date_value_1 },
  { name: 'Jenny', createdAt: some_date_value_2 }
]
```

What can I do to publish a result like this?

```
{
  some_date_value_1: [
    { name: 'John', createdAt: some_date_value_1 },
    { name: 'Bob', createdAt: some_date_value_1 }
  ],

  some_date_value_2: [
     { name: 'Jane', createdAt: some_date_value_2 },
     { name: 'Jenny', createdAt: some_date_value_2 }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of you want to do it on client or server.

First, the obvious solution: if you have no specific reason to store them with the first structure, store them directly using the second.

Second, another easy solution is to make in client. Here is a non tested code using undercore (bundled with meteor):

```
var yourCollection = CollectionName.find();
var yourCollectionByDate = _.groupBy(yourCollection , 'createdAt');
```

Third, you could still do it on server but either you will loose the reactivity of your collection (using for instance `Collection.aggregate` with a package) or have to transform and observe all changes afterwards (it would be a little overkill. However have a look [here if you want more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807390/build-a-reactive-publication-with-additional-fields-in-each-document/30813050?noredirect=1#comment49748876_30813050))

A quick side note too: unless you want the users names to be unique, you should rely on mongo unique id (`_.id`) rather than on a name you set. That way, you are sure that you link to the right item (no duplicate).

Comment: I opted for the first solution and changed the data structure. It was not obvious to me coming from SQL database. I also tried to do use the second solution in the server side, but it did not work because you can only publish an array, no an object.