# How to trigger a Client JS method when a subscribed data is changed

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I want my app to fire a method (client side) when a particular subscribed data is changed? for example, the client side has this following subscription

```
Meteor.subscribe('thePlayers');
```

`thePlayers` subscription returns a collection of data which is being displayed in the html through the template.

so whenever the collection get changed, Meteor automatically change the data in the HTML also. Besides this feature, I want my app to fire a method say `fire()` to be executed as soon as data get changed. What should i do to achieve this?

Comment: Without knowing more about what you are trying to do, I'd recommend looking at [observe changes](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes).

Answer (score 0):

As [David Weldon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635981/david-weldon) correctly, `cursor.observerChanges` is the way to go. Here's how you can use it for your example (assuming your collection is called `thePlayers`):

*client-side*

```
methodCaller = function (methodName) {
  return function (/* arguments */) {
    Meteor.apply(methodName, arguments)
  }
}

var fireCaller = methodCaller('fire')
thePlayers.find().observeChanges({
  added: fireCaller,
  changed: fireCaller,
  removed: fireCaller
})
```

Answer (score 0):

*In case you need this `fire()` to be run on server*, you don't need a method, you can just rely on the `observeChanges` feature or just `observe` in your publication. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807390/build-a-reactive-publication-with-additional-fields-in-each-document) to get an example of how you can achieve that.

*In case you need this `fire()` to be run on client*, keep in mind that every helper in your template is reactive, that means it will re-run each time your collection is changed. I assume that it requires that you use the subscription inside it, but that needs to be confirmed.