# How can I decrypt a cursor's documents, while publishing in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I am using this [Meteor AES encryption package](https://atmospherejs.com/altapp/aes) . On the server, I encrypt certain fields and save them to the mongo database. 
I'd like to decrypt these fields on a publish function. Is this possible and how can I do it?

I'm avoiding doing [decryption on the client](https://medium.com/meteor-js/client-side-aes-encryption-with-meteor-3be8d645fc12) because I imagine it's not safe to have the passphrase there written on the files that are visible in the browser.

Any suggestions are welcome, thank you.

Comment: Besides the fact that I'd like an architecture much better where encryption/decryption is exclusively done client-side, your best bet probably is to retrieve all documents in the publish function like you would do in any server-side method which is no publish function, decrypt them and then add them to the subscription of the user with `this.added()` inside the `publish` function (also see http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_added). When all documents are added don't forget to call `this.ready()`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried an approach that is essentially the same as you suggested. I wish I could do the decryption on the client, but the problem I see is having the passphrase written on the client files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a publication with additional or modified fields [like described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807390/build-a-reactive-publication-with-additional-fields-in-each-document). That would make your decrypted data available and reactive on client-side.