# Observers/hooks in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have some collections which are related to others through an ID.

For instance, I have collections `Post` and `Comments`. I want to display the number of comments to each posts. Therefore, I have a field in `Post` called `numComments`. I could update this number in a method every time a comment with same `postId` is either inserted og removed but I will instead use some hooks/observers to ensure the number is always updated.

Therefore, I have created a file `server/observers.js` with content

```
Comments.find().observe({
  added: function(document) {
    Posts.update({ postId: document.postId }, { $inc: { numComments: 1 } });
  },
  changed: function(document) {
  },
  removed: function(document) {
    Posts.update({ postId: document.postId }, { $inc: { numComments: -1 } });
  },
});
```

I like this kind of solution but is it a good way to do it?

My problem is that since I implemented this functionality, the console window prints an awful lot of errors/warnings. I suspect it is because of the observers.

In the documentation (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe), it says:

> observe returns a live query handle, which is an object with a stop method. Call stop with no arguments to stop calling the callback functions and tear down the query. The query will run forever until you call this (..)

I am not sure what it means but I think the observers should be stopped manually.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: @Morten You don't want to use an observe when you need a hook. Please see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190739/count-number-comments-in-post-in-meteor).

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30813050/3793161). It might lead you in the right direction, since the example is very similar to what you want. You don't need a dedicated field in your collection to get a reactive counting of your comments, you can build it in your publish function.

> I am not sure what it means but I think the observers should be
>   stopped manually

You're right. In the example linked above, the query is wrapped inside a `handle` variable. Notice the

```
self.onStop(function () {
  handle.stop();
});
```

It allows you to make sure that no observers will still be running once you stop publishing.