# Count number comments in post in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

If I want to count the number of comments a post has got, I will have to save the number of comments every time a new comment is either created or removed.

What is the most efficient and secure way to ensure the posts are updated with the number of comments every time a comment is either created or removed? I have tried `Curser.observe()` but it seems it causes some problems sometimes. I have looked through my code and it should be OK but sometimes some changes happend when they shouldn't so I'm afraid that observe() causes some problems when multiple objects are created at the same time.

I have looked at `meteor-collection-hooks` and they don't use `observe`. I thought `observe` was the best choice since it is native. How does others solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use observe. It consumes resources and doesn't scale past one server (in N servers are observing the change, you will have N increments). I can recommend two possible options:

**hooks**

As you suggested, you can use [collection-hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) to modify the count. Specifically you'd probably want to use [after.insert](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks#afterinsertuserid-doc) and [after.remove](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks#afterremoveuserid-doc) on your `Comments` collection. Hooks don't require extra resources - they just patch the underlying collection code to run your callback.

Recommended reading: [A Look At Meteor Collection Hooks](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-look-at-meteor-collection-hooks/)

**methods**

If you use [methods](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods) to insert and remove your comments, you can also modify your comment counts at the same time. This has the advantage of not requiring an external package, however it also requires some mixing of concerns in your methods.

Comment: Thank you! Glad to finally understand why they increased rapidly without no reason :D