# Meteor Avg Aggregate from Publish to Helpers

Tags: javascript, meteor, aggregate, publish, helper

I'm working on a meteor project where I need to get the average of review scores. I came across meteorhacks:aggregate package but wasn't able to implement it.

Publish:

```
Meteor.publish('supplierReviewsOverall', function(userid){

var pipeline = [
    {
        $match: {
            supplier: userid
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            rate_overall : { $avg: "$rate_overall" },
            rate_timeliness : { $avg: "$rate_timeliness" },
            rate_quality : { $avg: "$rate_quality" },
            rate_value : { $avg: "$rate_value" }
        }
    }
]

return SupplierReviews.aggregate(pipeline);
});
```

And I'm getting this error: Error: Publish function returned an array of non-Cursors.

Then, how am I going to get the value to the helper so I can put the data in HTML??

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

basic answer: this is because you need to return a `Cursor` in a publication.

You have too possibilities:

1. You can recreate a cursor using your aggregation result but be warned, you will loose reactivity: it means that except when you reload your template, you will not get external updates. To achieve that, you just need to wrap your `SupplierReviews.aggregate(pipeline);` into a `var buffer = SupplierReviews.aggregate(pipeline);` and iterate on it to add each item of your array into your publication cursor:

   `_(buffer).each(function(item){
      self.added ('SupplierReviews', item._id, item);
    };
    self.ready();`
2. My personnal favorite: you don't need to aggregate (and loose reactivity to achieve an `average` operation. You can use a simple `Collection.find()` query and extend/reduce/modify it using a clever mix of `cursor.Observe` and conditional modifications. Have a look at this answer, it did the trick for me (I needed a sum, but you can easily adapt it to an average) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30813050/3793161
3. If you plan to have several servers, be warned that each server will have to `observe` so it may lead to an unnecessary load. So my third solution is either [use collection hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) or methods to update an additional field `average` for each value you need. See @David Weldon answer about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31190896/3793161

Comment: Thanks for this! I like the first approach even though I will loose reactivity. My question is, how can I access it in helper so I can print it out in the view? Thanks!

Comment: You need to subscribe to your publication. Once you have, you can access your data in the template data context if you bind it to it. Inside your helper, depending where it is it would be `this.data.yourData` or `this.yourData`. Second solution, you will have direct access to a minimongo version of `SupplierReviews` collection. You can access it "directly" with a `SupplierReviews.find()`. Have a look here for a better understanding: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/