# MongoDB Grouping Query

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm working on a Meteor application and I have data for a weekly timetable of the format -

```
events:
    event:
       day: "Monday"
       time: "9am"
       location: "A"
    event:
       day: "Monday"
       time: "10am"
       location: "B"
```

There are numerous entries for each day. Can I run a query that will return an object of the format -

```
day: "Monday"
   events:
      event:
         time: "9am"
         location: "A"
      event:
         time: "10am"
         location: "B"
```

I could store the object in the second format but prefer the first for ease of deleting and updating individual events.

I also want to return them ordered by day of week if there's a nice way to do that.

Comment: Can you show us the exact MongoDB document schema that represents the above data?

Comment: `event = {
 "_id" : int,
 "day" : string,
 "time" : string,
 "location" : string
}`

Comment: I'll have a form for adding a new event, deleting or modifying but when I'm displaying them they will be grouped by Day. I know I can do this all in the front end but it might be tidier done in the query. First time doing this so could have it all wrong.

Comment: @kinsey so you need these data to be sorted and grouped at the time of the publish or is this only for display purposes? I.e. are the event documents already on the client when you need to reshape them?

Comment: Only needed for display purposes - I see now that the day is actually being stored as an int rather than a String so sorting is easy. The day string is selected from a Select box with numberic values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several options:

1. You can use an aggregation command but be warned, you will loose reactivity: it means that except when you reload your template, you will not get external updates. You would also need to use [a package to add the aggregation command to Meteor](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate/) in order to achieve that.
2. My personal favorite: you don't need to aggregate (and loose reactivity) to achieve your data transformation. You can use a simple `Collection.find()` query and extend/reduce/modify it using a clever mix of `cursor.Observe()` and conditional modifications. Have a look at this answer, it did the trick for me (I needed a sum with black listing of some fields, but you can easily adapt it to your group/sorting case) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30813050/3793161. Comment if you need more details on this
3. If you plan to have several servers, be warned that each server will have to observe so it may lead to an unnecessary load. So my third solution is either use collection hooks or methods to update an additional field containing every event for each day/user (whatever you need).See @David Weldon answer about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31190896/3793161. In you case, it would probably mean to re-think your database structure to fit your needs (i.e. adding more fields so you ca update them on `insert`.

---

**EDIT** Here are some thoughts on your comment:

If you stick to what you described in the question, you would need seven documents, one per day, with an `events` field where you put all the events. My second solution is good if you need to rework a collection structure before sending it. However, in your case, you just need an object `week` with 7 sub-objects matching the days of the week.

I advise you to possible approaches:

- use the aggregation in a method, as described by @chridam. Be warned that you will not be able to directly get a sorted array, as stated in mongo `$group` documentation

> $group does not order its output documents

So you need to sort them (by day *and* by hour within each day) using, for example `_.sortBy()` before you return your method result. By the way, if you want to know what is going on in your method call, *clientside*, here is how you should write the call:

```
Meteor.call("getGroupedDailyEvents", userId, function(error, result){ 
    if(error){ 
        console.log("error", error); 
    } 
    if(result){ 
         //do whatever you need
    } 
});
```

- Make the data sorting client-side. You are looking for an overkill solution because, afaik, you don't need to filter any data to keep it from the user, and you are going to send the data anyway (just with another structure). This is much easier to make a simple helper in your template like this:

  ```
  Template.displaySchedule.helpers({

      "monday_events": function() {
          return _.sortBy (events.find({day:"Monday"}).fetch(), "time")
      },
      //add other days
  );
  ```

It assumes the format of your `time` field is sortable this way. If not, you just need to create a function to sort them accordingly to their formats or change the original format into something better suited.

The rest (HTML) would just be to iterate on Monday events using a `{{#each monday_events}}`

Comment: In my case, I don't think losing reactivity is an issue so option 1 would work if I could get it right. I'm also interested in option 2 but don't really get it. I'll continue to read through your example and would appreciate a rough guideline of how it would apply to my case. 3, its a small app and won't be running on several servers.

Comment: You're right about the aggregation approach being overkill in this example. I was thinking that doing it this way would simplify the code elsewhere. Since the code it's simplifying isn't particularly complicated its definitely over the top. Your second option is the way to do it. Good learning exercise for me though and I will get the aggregator example working first. The days are actually stored as numbers 1-7 so I can simplify it further by replacing "monday_events" with something more generic and pass in an integer creating a new row for each day.

Comment: I am glad I helped. If you think this answer solved your problem, consider validating it.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired result, use the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** where the **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline operator groups all the input documents and apply the accumulator expression **[`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** to the group to get the events array.

Your pipeline would look like this:

```
var Events = new Mongo.Collection('events');
var pipeline = [        
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$day",
            "events": {
                "$push": {
                    "time": "$time"
                    "location": "$location"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, "day": "$_id", "events": 1
        }
    }
];
var result = Events.aggregate(pipeline);
console.log(result)
```

You can add the **[meteorhacks:aggregate package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate)** to implement the aggregation in Meteor:

Add to your app with

```
meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate
```

Since this package exposes **`.aggregate`** method on Mongo.Collection instances, you can define a method that gets the aggregated result array. For example

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    var Events = new Mongo.Collection('events');
    Meteor.methods({
        getGroupedDailyEvents: function () {
            var pipeline = [        
                {
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": "$day",
                        "events": {
                            "$push": {
                                "time": "$time"
                                "location": "$location"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$project": {
                        "_id": 0, "day": "$_id", "events": 1
                    }
                }
            ];
            var result = Events.aggregate(pipeline);
            return result;
        }
    }); 
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.call('getGroupedDailyEvents', logResult);

    function logResult(err, res) {
        console.log("Result: ", res)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! I can follow your example okay but when i call the function I'm not getting a response.
   `Meteor.methods({
 'getTrainingList': function(){
  var pipeline = [
  {
          $group: {
            _id: '$day',
            training: {
              $push: {
                time: '$time',
                location: '$location'
              }
            }
          }
        }/*, 
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0, day: '$_id', training: 1
          }
        }*/
   ];
   var result = TrainingList.aggregate(pipeline);
      return result;
 }
  });`

Comment: @kinsey How are you calling the function?

Comment: sorry ignore those opening/closing comment tags.. that code is included

Comment: if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.call('getTrainingList');
  }

Comment: I also have a subscription to TrainingList in the client and i can see that there are a bunch of entries in there with the correct format

Comment: From the [**`Meteor.call`**](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call) documentation: _On the client, if you do not pass a callback and you are not inside a stub, call will return undefined, and you will have no way to get the return value of the method. That is because the client doesn't have fibers, so there is not actually any way it can block on the remote execution of a method._ You need to call the function with a callback like `if (Meteor.isClient) { Meteor.call('getTrainingList', function (err, res) { console.log(res); }); } `

Comment: Ah okay! I am just getting undefined. That looks like something that could certainly resolve my issue. I won't be able to try it out until tonight. Will let you know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @kinsey No worries, let me know how that goes once you get around the issue.

Comment: Instantly fixed it :)