# how to execute native mongo methods in meteor app environment?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Meteor supports only few methods on mongo collections such as *find, findOne, insert, update, upsert, remove, allow, deny*
My question is, how do I perform all the others? I want to use aggregate on server side, like this:

```
db.eshops.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: '$unpairedCategories'
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      'sum': {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total_sum: {
        '$sum': '$sum'
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

should I include mongodb driver for nodejs separately from meteor? Or what is the meteor way to run all the other mongo collection methods?

Comment: I found that I can easily use mongo aggregate with meteorhacks:aggregate package https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate/

Comment: FYI this package is using `cursor.observe`, the second alternative I mentioned.  I noticed that you didn't validate the answer. Please do if you consider it was correct/helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of [the seven principles of Meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/sevenprinciples) is *database everywhere*, i.e. you should be able to perform all the allowed operations both on client and server side (assuming several differences, such as `allow deny` rules for client). I guess this is why you can't have all mongo methods: they are not feasible on minimongo, the client side version of your mongo collection.

However, if you are ready **to give up the reactivity**, you can create a pipe to handle the `aggregate` commands, by adding this to your server startup code ([code taken from here](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate/blob/master/index.js)):

```
wrapAsync = (Meteor.wrapAsync)? Meteor.wrapAsync : Meteor._wrapAsync;
Mongo.Collection.prototype.aggregate = function(pipelines) {
  var coll;
  if (this.rawCollection) {
    // >= Meteor 1.0.4
    coll = this.rawCollection();
  } else {
    // < Meteor 1.0.4
    coll = this._getCollection();
  }
  return wrapAsync(coll.aggregate.bind(coll))(pipelines);
```

You have two possible alternatives/workaround if you want to keep the reactivity.

1. create extra fields [using](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-look-at-meteor-collection-hooks/) [collection hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks). You basically include the computed fields in the collection. This is a scalable solution, and it does not requires to add an extra load to the server
2. You use the `cursor.Observe()` feature and you make a mix of clever filtering and custom JS methods (e.g. sum) to achieve similar results to what you need from the `aggregate` method. Note that you keep the reactivity but each server (if you plan to scale on several) needs to `Observe()` the collections. Check this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30813050/3793161