# Reactively show number of unread comments in a thread?

Tags: meteor

I'm making a forum type app with Threads and Comments within a Thread. I'm trying to figure out how to show the total number of unread comments within a thread to each user.

I considered publishing all the Comments for every Thread, but this seems like excessive data to be publishing to the client when all I want is a single number showing the unread Comments. But if I start adding metadata to the Thread collection (such as numComments, numCommentsUnread...), this adds extra moving parts to the app (i.e. I have to track every time a different user adds a Comment to a Thread, etc...).

What are some of the best practices for dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Publish-Counts package (https://github.com/percolatestudio/publish-counts) if all you need is the count. If you need the actual related comments take a look at the meteor-composite-publish (https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite) package.

Comment: I've looked into Publish-Counts. Doesn't Publish-Counts only return a single number? That would work if I was just looking for a the total count of Threads. But each thread has multiple comments, which I'm trying to get the count of.

Comment: Publish-Counts takes a name and a cursor. The cursor can be for the comments collection and you can specify a projection to the find method to only return those for the specific thread that you are on. For example: Counts.publish(this, 'name-of-counter', Comments.find({}, {threadId: "the-thread-Id"}));

Comment: The above can go into any publication, even that of a Thread.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a database design problem.

You will have to keep a collection of UserThreads, which tracks when the last time the user checked the thread. It has the userId, the threadId, and the lastViewed date(or whatever sensible alternatives you might use).

IF the user has never checked the thread then do not have an object in the UserThreads then the unread count would be the comment count.

WHEN the user views the thread for the first time, create a UserThread object for him.

UPDATE the lastViewed on the UserThread whenever he views the thread.

The UnreadCommentCount will be calculated reactively. It is the sum of comments on the thread where the comment's createdAt is newer than the lastViewed on the UserThread. This can be a template helper function that is executed in the view on an as needed basis. For example, when listing Threads in a subforum view, then it would only calculate for the Threads being viewed in that list at that time.

Alternatively, you could keep an unreadCommentCount attribute on the UserThread. Every time a comment is posted to the thread, then you would iterate through that Thread's UserThreads, updating the unreadCommentCount. When the user later visits that thread, you then reset the unreadCommentCount to zero and updated the lastViewed. The user would then subscribe to a publication of his own UserThreads, which would update reactively.

It seems that in building a forum type site that UserThread object would be indispensable for tracking how a User interacts with Threads. If he had viewed it, ignored it, has commented in it, wants to subscribe to it but has not commented yet, etc.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Can you elaborate on what you mean by UnreadCommentCount will be calculated reactively? I thought this number would just be static and not reactive. Is it updated every time a user posts a new comment to a thread?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @datacarl [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30813050/3793161), you can modify your thread publication to integrate additional data, such as a count of your unread comments. Here is how you can achieve it, using `Cursor.observe()`.

```
var self = this;

// Modify the document we are sending to the client.
function filter(doc) {
  var length = doc.item.length;

  // White list the fields you want to publish.
  var docToPublish = _.pick(doc, [
      'someOtherField'
  ]);

  // Add your custom fields.
  docToPublish.itemLength = length;

  return docToPublish;                        
}

var handle = myCollection.find({}, {fields: {item:1, someOtherField:1}})
            // Use observe since it gives us the the old and new document when something is changing. 
            // If this becomes a performance issue then consider using observeChanges, 
            // but its usually a lot simpler to use observe in cases like this.
            .observe({
                added: function(doc) {
                    self.added("myCollection", doc._id, filter(doc));
                },
                changed: function(newDocument, oldDocument)
                    // When the item count is changing, send update to client.
                    if (newDocument.item.length !== oldDocument.item.length)
                        self.changed("myCollection", newDocument._id, filter(newDocument));
                },

                removed: function(doc) {
                    self.removed("myCollection", doc._id);                    
                });

self.ready();

self.onStop(function () {
  handle.stop();
});
```

I guess you can adapt this example to your case. You can remove the white list part if you need to. The count part will be covered using a request such as `post.find({"unread":true, "thread_id": doc._id}).count()`

---

Another way to achieve that is to use [collection hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks). Each time you insert a comment, you hook on after the insert and you update a dedicated field "unread comments count" in your related thread document. Each time, [the user read a post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31769877/3793161), you update the value.