# Collections created using MongoDB's aggregation $out option are not observable via Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

What could be different about the collections created aggregate([$out])  than insert()?

See demo of problem here: meteor-aggregation-issue.meteor.com

Seems like Mongo's aggregate() when using $out, somehow produces a different collection than an insert() of the same data. I'm only guessing this because I'm getting very different behaviors.

I'm testing this in Meteor, and collections created with aggregate([$out])  are not observable by the app. I'm not sure why this would be the case, since the collection looks fine in the Mongo console.

Here is the app that can reproduce the error:
https://github.com/keyscores/meteor-aggregation-issue
just clone and cd to the app, and run >meteor

*EDIT*

From my post in the Mongo issue tracker: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19958
Charlie Swanson:

"
An aggregate command with an $out stage will create a temporary collection while the aggregation pipeline is running, and then, once the pipeline is done, it will rename the temporary collection to the name specified in the $out stage. e.g. if you ran

db.foo.aggregate([{$out: 'bar'}]);

It would create a temporary bar.tmp.agg_out collection, and insert all the results from the pipeline into that collection. When the pipeline completes, it will rename bar.tmp.agg_out to bar, keeping all indices and options of the existing bar collection (if any).

This should explain the behavior you are seeing. If I understand your code correctly, Meteor is providing a framework to let you listen to events, such as a document being inserted into a collection, and it is not calling the callback when you use an aggregate() command? As a temporary workaround, could you verify that listening to those events on the ".tmp.agg_out" collection would work?
"

Answer (score 0):

I assume that if you use `aggregate()` functions, you installed a package [such as this one](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate/), or added a pipe for `aggregate()` functions to your app.

The reason why your collection is not observable is because it is not reactive. As far as I know, you can't observe a non reactive source of data.

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30813050/3793161), it was my work-around when I had the same issue. Depending on your case, you can also use [collection hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) to prepare a simple `Collection.find()` request.

Comment: Is there a reason a collection would not be reactive? If you look at my example ( https://github.com/keyscores/meteor-aggregation-issue ) the collection is reactive when I update it from a mongo console. Just not from aggregate()

Comment: I can't give you a definitive answer. All I can say is that I experienced the same (console update working/aggregation not working) but it makes sense if you consider that `aggregate()` is not a built-in function of Meteor (i.e. the reactivity has not been implemented for it) and once your aggregation is done, your client is just modifying an already published table.

Comment: Thanks Billybobbonnet, as you say what is strange is that the same collection can be updated by the console, and get a reactive update. How would aggregate() by different than an insert()?

Comment: Think about the latency compensation. Your minimongo collection is updated before your actual collection is. Changes are rolled back if the query is not allowed by the native driver allow/deny rules. So it makes sense that you can change the collection in the console. This is a client driven change, so it is updated for him, but not for other clients (who already subscribed) I assume.. Again, I think you can publish almost anything using the technique described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30813050/3793161. This is more tricky than an aggregation, but much more flexible imho.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean browser console. I meant the mongo console itself. >meteor mongo. What I mean is: the same collection when using insert() directly on mongo admin console will appear reactively.  This is outside the meteor loop. And even so it is reactive. I'm not sure why $out would be any different than insert()

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood you about the console. This is an interesting observation, but I don't know the why. You still can use a `Cursor.observe()` on a basic find query (on the $out collection), and use a function inside each added/changed/removed to add the content you wanted to import in your collection using $out

Comment: Yes I have done something similar in the code https://github.com/keyscores/meteor-aggregation-issue . The issue is that I'll be consuming cycles and RAM on the app server, instead of doing it all in mongo.

Comment: Well, sure, you'll be consuming cycles and RAM on the app server, instead of doing it all in mongo since you are doing the work there. If you really want to avoid that, use collection hooks. I am not sure, since I don't know your case, how to make it work, but I am slowly transitioning from a `Cursor.observe()` approach to a collection hooks approach and it is looking good.

Comment: Basically, you trade RAM consumption on app server against more requests to mongo. And you can scale up to several app servers without worries. By the way, you went to great lengths for this example app. If had not upvoted  your question already, I would :)

Comment: Thanks :) Can I get you to +1 it on: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4947

Comment: not that I don't want to put the +1, but you can't flag it as a bug. It is just a feature that hasn't been implemented yet. It could be partially reactive in some context (and not in some other contexts) for reasons out of my league, but as long as it is not officially supported, you can't consider it has to be reactive. To cite @arunoda: "There is no reactivity built into this and I don't know a solution for reactivity for aggregations other than polling."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87029/discussion-between-lpg-and-billybobbonnet).

Comment: FYI From Mongo Issue Tracker
Charlie Swanson:
"
An aggregate command with an $out stage will create a temporary collection while the aggregation pipeline is running, and then, once the pipeline is done, it will rename the temporary collection to the name specified in the $out stage. e.g. if you ran

db.foo.aggregate([{$out: 'bar'}]);

It would create a temporary bar.tmp.agg_out collection, and insert all the results from the pipeline into that collection. When the pipeline completes, it will rename bar.tmp.agg_out to bar, keeping all indices and options of the existing bar collection (if any).